# Is is possible to generate slides using blogdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, blogdown, reveal.js

On my blogdown-powered site I'd like to also host some slides, which I often build with R Markdown and revealjs. But when I add a `slides.Rmd` file into some content directory, it just generates an ordinary web page using the Hugo theme configured, but not the RevealJS slides.

Is it possible to configure blogdown or an R markdown file (using its front-matter) to build slides?

Comment: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/static-files.html